# Django removing object from ManyToMany relationship

Tags: django, many-to-many

How would I delete an object from a Many-to-Many relationship without removing the actual object?

**Example:**

I have the models `Moods` and `Interest`.

`Mood` has a many-to-many field `interests` (which is a `models.ManyToManyField(Interest)`).

I create an instance of `Moods` called `my_mood`. In `my_moods`'s interests field I have `my_interest`, meaning

```
>>> my_mood.interests.all()
[my_interest, ...]
```

How do I remove `my_interest` from `my_mood` without deleting either model instance? In other words, how do I remove the relationship without affecting the related models?

Answer (score 293, accepted):

```
my_mood.interests.remove(my_interest)
```

[Django's Relations Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.remove)

Note: you might have to get an instance of `my_mood` and `my_interest` using [Django's QuerySet API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/) before you can execute this code.

Comment: `AttributeError: 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'remove'`

Comment: to add another `entry my_mood.interests.add(my_interest)`

Comment: @Cerin: (sorry for bumping an old comment) The question is about m2m, which implies a `ManyRelatedManager`, not a `RelatedManager`. That explains the `AttributeError`.

Comment: Note that [ManyRelatedManager.remove()](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/4.0.x/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py#L964) also accepts object `id`s.

Comment: don't forget to call `my_mood.save()`

Comment: You can remove a list or queryset like this: `my_mood.interests.remove(*interest_queryset)`

Answer (score 128):

If you need to remove all M2M references without touching the underlying objects, it's easier to work from the other direction:

```
interest.mood_set.clear()
```

While this does not directly address the OP's question, it's often useful in this situation.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Granted it does not specifically address the OP's question, but I left the answer because it is of specific interest to people grappling with removing relations in M2M contexts, and removes the need to loop through instances. I thought it was a helpful related tip.

Comment: This was just useful to me (I was about to loop through and didn't want to).  Thanks for posting it!

Comment: it could be better if you just add this point in above answer

Comment: Or with related name in models and `interest.relatedname.clear()`

Answer (score 24):

In your case you can simply clear the relationship

```
my_mood.interests.clear()
```

Then perhaps when you are again creating new relation in your serializer you can do something like this

```
interests = Interests.objects.get_or_create(name='Something')
my_mood_obj.tags.add(tag[0])
my_mood_obj.save()
```

Comment: Since add immediately affects the database, you do not need to save afterwards ;)

Answer (score -1):

`model.field.remove(object_you_want_to_remove)` 
In this case use: `my_mood.interests.remove(my_interest)`

Comment: simple duplicate of the correct answer.