# Django retrieving data from m2m table

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am using Django default User model. I've made a relation m2m to it with model Books. Django made automaticly table in library app - library_books_user. How can I get acces to it? I want to be able to delete relations.

Normally when I use not built in models i can do it like: models.BooksUsers.objects.get(book=book, user=user) importing models before.

Answer (score 0):

You need the instance of book and user then you can delete the user relation from the Book model like this.

```
user = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
book = Book.objects.get(pk=pk)

book.users.remove(user)
```

Ex: [Django removing object from ManyToMany relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333068/django-removing-object-from-manytomany-relationship)